# Firebase security with angularfire

Tags: angularfire, firebase-security

I'm new to firebase and angularfire.  AngularJS is client side code. Its public to anyone.  What prevents a hacker from taking the following firebase reference, and using it in another app?

```
 var peopleRef = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/people");
 $scope.people = $firebase(peopleRef);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that Firebase has security rules surrounding who can do what with your data. So, I think you can specify users in your firebase that can have read/write permissions. I have never used them, but you can read about them here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html

Comment: Yes, you'll have to implement security rules on your Firebase to allow only authorized users to read/write data.

Comment: I'm curious, however, if an app can authenticate itself without exposing credentials publicly.  I'm talking about allowing a javascript app access without asking a person to sign in.  Is this even possible? Seems like there would have to be a server-side component so you don't expose the firebase credentials via Javascript.